# SpringBoot загрузка внешних JAR файлов в Runtime

Tags: java, spring-boot

Есть приложения(одно WAR, деплоится в Tomcat, и JAR - запускается самостоятельно)

Оба написанны с использованием **SpringBoot 1.5**

Есть необходимость запуска таким образом, чтобы можно было подключить внешние файлы **JAR**, чтобы они попали в **classpath**(т.е. так называемые "плагины")

Проблема в том, что в тех самых внешних **JAR** файлах содержится конфигурация(классы помеченные **@Configuration**)

То есть предполагаемая логика такая:

1. Поднимается основное приложение
2. Поднимаются классы из внешних библиотек
3. Поднимается конфигурация и контекст(как буд-то если бы эти библиотеки были подключенны напрямую в основной POM файл)

**Вопросы**:

1. как правильно собрать такие внешние библиотеки?
2. как сделать добавление этих файлов в контекст приложения, чтобы они заработали?

**P.S.**: пробовал через указание -Dloader.path ... не вышло(в основной модуль **@Autowired** не подтягивает реализации интерефйсов из внешних файлов)

**UPD**

С модулем, который запускается как JAR проблему смогли решить и с помощью [PropertiesLauncher](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/loader/PropertiesLauncher.html) и(как второй вариант) - с ипользованием **BeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessor**. Но с модклем, который потом деплоится в Tomcat - нет. Видимо из-за порядка прогрузки классов

Comment: СпрингБут сканирует от корня приложения + пути, какие ему отдельно указаны. Если у тебя приложение `my.company.App`, а плагины `some.company.Plugin`, то он не найдёт. В таком случае в приложении надо `@ComponentScan` указывать и добавлять пути. Что за задача такая странная изначально?

Comment: @AlexanderPavlov идея такова задачи( Есть веб сервис, с методами API. Вот ему динамически надо подкидывать реализации в виде JAR файликов. Идея грубо говоря в том, чтобы не переписывать постоянно сервис сам, а использовать существующий. А логику добрасывать реализацией в виде JAR библиотек

Comment: Можно всё иметь в одном JAR, а реализации выбирать с помощью средств Спринг/СпрингБут - profiles, conditional beans

Comment: Идея была именно в динамической подгрузке, без упаковки

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не в правилах отвечать на свои же вопросы, но всё же напишу(может кому-то понадобится) как выкрутились мы:

1. В классах, что в отдельных **JAR**(подгружаемых) реализовали интерфейс **FactoryBean**.
   Также завели свою аннотацию, которой пометили сови классы
2. Реализовали класс сканирования дирректории и подгрузки файлов в **ClassLoader**(Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader())
3. На конечных модулях(**WAR** и **JAR**) добавили класс конфигурации, реализующий **BeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessor**.
   В нём вызвали подгрузку классов из п.2, отфильтровали по аннотации и добавили их как бины(**registry.registerBeanDefinition**)

**UPD**: краткие листинги

1. Подгружаемый класс

   ```
   @LoadedClass
   public class MyLoaded implements FactoryBean<Loaded> {

      @Value("${params}")
      private String params;

      ...........

    }
   ```
2. Конфигурация для подгрузки

   ```
   @Configuration
   public class LoaderConfiguration implements BeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessor {

   /**
    * {@inheritDoc}
    */
   @Override
   public void postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(BeanDefinitionRegistry registry) throws BeansException {
       String dir = "/opt/";
       //Класс по поиску и подгрузки классов
       new Loader(dir).load((Class<?> t) -> {
           if (null != t.getAnnotation(LoadedClass.class)) {
               BeanDefinition someConfig = BeanDefinitionBuilder
                       .rootBeanDefinition(t)
                       .getBeanDefinition();
               registry.registerBeanDefinition(t.getSimpleName(), someConfig);
           }
       });
     }

   }
   ```